# Storing a number of 100 digits in C++ for basic arithmetic functions

Tags: c++

I am trying to write code for computing prime numbers of up to 100 digits and then performing basic arithmetic operations on it like `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`. I have done some research and found that this could be performed by using strings. But if I store the number in a string then how would I perform operations on it?

Comment: Hint : how do kids do arithmetic operations in schools? If they want to add two numbers, then they take two digits from each number and then add them, and they repeat this for all pairs of digits; in the process they also take care of the digit in 10th place, of the sum of two digits.

Comment: You can do a naive implementation using arrays of ints or you can use an existing library like GMP. Look for arbitrary-precision arithmetic.

Comment: [Big Int Libs](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+BigInt&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic 100 digits is not very much. For performance, use base 2^32 or 2^64 depending on your system

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a big integer class (or use an existing one).
For example: https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/

Answer (score 1):

It's not optimal for performance, but if you are to keep them as a string, you can do it like you would on paper.

```
  12345
    *54
 _______
  49380
+617250
 _______
 666630
```

It should be the simplest to conceive and can be extended as long as your string type will allow. Temporary numbers will be required, but the results never exceed 8 bits either.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky, but you need to process the string chunks at a time. That is, read several digits from your strings and treat those as a number and do partial arithmetic on that. You will have to remember to carry over digits when you do this.

Multiplication and division is even more complicated, but it's possible to do using a similar system.

Comment: no i cant use any language other than the c++ . what do you mean by partial airthmetic